# Boost Building using visual studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to build `boost`, I have both `visual studio 2005` and `visual studio 2010` installed on my machine when I ran `bootstrap.bat` it by default taken `visual studio 2010`. How do I force this to build with `visual studio 2005`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On bjam (or b2) command-line try adding the following "toolset=msvc-8.0"